# 「のに」と「ので」の使い方についての質問です。

Tags: grammar

下記の文では、「のに」のかわりに「ので」が使えるでしょうか。使える場合、その意味は同じでしょうか。違うでしょうか。

> みんなが頑張っているのに、私が頑張らないわけにはいきません。

お答え、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. みんなが頑張っているのに、私が頑張らないわけにはいきません。
> 2. みんなが頑張っているので、私が頑張らないわけにはいきません。

Yes, these two sentences are both correct, and mean the same thing.

Why? In Sentence 1, everything before わけ modifies わけ. In Sentence 2, only 私が頑張らない modifies わけ, and the clause before the comma is independent.

> 1. [みんなが頑張っているのに、私が頑張らない]わけにはいきません。
>      There is no way [that I won't do my best *although* everyone is doing their best].
> 2. みんなが頑張っているので、[私が頑張らない]わけにはいきません。
>      There is no way [that I won't do my best], because everyone is doing their best.

Lastly, if you're concerned about this comma, please [read this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23782/5010).

Comment: Out of curiosity, I followed the link on the comma usage.  What a pleasant surprise to find 夢十夜 on the other end.  When I first read that 25 years ago, I struggled so hard to understand it.  Now I reread it, I have a hard time remembering why I found it difficult so many years ago.  But today, it's like rediscovering an old half-forgotten treasure.  Thank you.