# Can we use a comma to separate the noun of a relative clause verb?

Tags: relative-clauses

> 「ひとはだれしもが、心に灯台を持っている。その光に従って生きるだけで幸福になれる」と信じる著者が綴った、奇跡のファンタジー体験ノベル！

Is the comma after `綴った` separating the `奇跡のファンタジー体験ノベル` from `綴った`, or the sentence ends in `綴った`?

Also, how can I translate `奇跡のファンタジー体験ノベル`?

A fantasy experience novel of/about a miracle...? Is the order after の the same as in English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(～と信じる作者が)綴った is a relative clause that modifies 奇跡のファンタジー体験ノベル. [Don't be deceived by the comma](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23782/5010).

奇跡の ("miraculous") is a no-adjective, and it's just another common marketing phrase. However, ファンタジー体験ノベル is not a common phrase/genre, and I don't even know if this refers to a fiction or a non-fiction. It may be a ファンタジー小説 (fiction) with a 体験 element, or it may be a 体験小説 (non-fiction) with a fantasy element...